# Почему выдается следующая ошибка?

Tags: php, denwer, mysql

Ошибка:

mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on line 30

При коде:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345");
mysql_select_db("movie_site", connect);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date, title, movies, images FROM movies", connect);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Перевести, что ли, надо?

Comment: Я понимаю. Но зачем? Смотрите в config file:

     /* User used to manipulate with storage */
     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '12345';


Так в чем же проблема?

Comment: При чём тут конфиг? Запустите в консоли "mysql -u root --password=12345" и узнаете.

Comment: кстати это я в денвере. Написал в консоль, ничего в ответ. Пишет: не является командой

Comment: Значит, ищите куда установлен mysql, где-то там файл mysql.exe.

Comment: нашел. А потом? Приписал туда это, пишет ошибка в синтаксисе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Денвере база без пароля по умолчанию. Я подразумеваю, что вы ничего не трогали и выставляли пароль для юзера **root**, раз задаете такого рода вопрос. Тогда просто напишите в ваших файлах

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

Сойдет за конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос - он решит вашу проблему. Вдаваться в подробности настроек **MySQL** здесь не буду.